# How to load dropdown options when overriding form template in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

**Background**

In Symfony 2.8, I'm using [the doc's explanation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_customization.html) on how to customize form rendering. Works just fine.

But I'm having a problem whereby the options in my `<select>` aren't showing up, because of course in the form template twig file, I've overwritten the element.

**Question**

Can I retrieve the options from the `form` variable somehow, so I can load them into the `<select>` element manually?

**Side note**

I know SF2.8 has reached EoL last month, and the upgrade is underway.

Answer (score 0):

For my answer I presume that your form is named `form` and the select name is `select`, you can access all values with

```
form.select.vars.value
```

This will return a list (array) of values you can iterate to obtain single values.